# MySQL INSERT if one of primary key value doesn't match

Tags: mysql, insert, unique-key, not-exists

I would like to do MySQL query like this:

```
if((value1 != dbPrimaryValue1) OR (value2 != dbPrimaryValue2))
      INSERT ROW
else
      DO NOTHING
```

Lets try example:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp` (
    `one` int NOT NULL,
    `two` int NOT NULL,
    `three` int NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE `tmp`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`one`, `two`);

INSERT INTO `tmp`
    (`one`, `two`, `three`)
    VALUES (1,2,3);

INSERT INTO `tmp`
    (`one`,`two`,`three`) 
    VALUES (10,20,30),
           (1,999,999),
       (999,2,999),
       (1,2,999)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
           UPDATE `one` = `one`; // or some dummy no-source-drain operation
```

Result is here:

```
select * from tmp;
+-----+-----+-------+
| one | two | three |
+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 |   2 |     3 |
|  10 |  20 |    30 |
|   1 | 999 |   999 |
| 999 |   2 |   999 |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

**U would like to have result like this:**

```
 select * from tmp;
+-----+-----+-------+
| one | two | three |
+-----+-----+-------+
|   1 |   2 |     3 |
|  10 |  20 |    30 |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

Is it possible to make this query? I'm operating with huge data and procedure like  *load -> compare -> save* is not possible.  THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make both fields unique separately. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp` (
    `one` int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `two` int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `three` int NOT NULL);
```

Or add the constraints via:

```
ALTER TABLE `tmp` ADD UNIQUE (`one`);
ALTER TABLE `tmp` ADD UNIQUE (`two`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `UNIQUE` key constraint, the database will not allow you to insert them automatically.

From [MySQL forum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html):

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint
>   such that all values in the index must
>   be distinct. An error occurs if you
>   try to add a new row with a key value
>   that matches an existing row. For all
>   engines, a UNIQUE index permits
>   multiple NULL values for columns that
>   can contain NULL.